# ASP.net application events not firing after published

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have written and tested out my asp.net application, and it works fine in debug mode.  However, when I publish it to IIS, it seems my events only fire sometimes. The events are a textbox text change event and a timer tick event.

Timer aspx:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="True" Interval="500"
           ViewStateMode="Enabled">
</asp:Timer>
```

Textbox aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
             Height="101px" Width="350px"
             OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: please share code

Comment: Can you confirm you have deployed everything in IIS? First, check date and hour. In particular, is the DLL up-to-date? Even if you copy aspx files, code behind with the event handlers are compiled into the DLL for the project. Second, check Windows Event Viewer.